# How to move the footer margin closer to the bottom, manually

Tags: header-footer, margins, footnotes

I have a page built in latex that has a footnote. I am not happy with the distance from the bottom to the footnote: it is too large. I want to have a bigger place to write, so I want the footnote to be close to the bottom.

Also, I want to do this "manually", similar to the way that I did with the top distance:

```
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you thought about using the `geometry` pacakge?

Comment: Looking for something like `\addtolength{\textheight}{15pt}`?

Comment: @karkoeller yes, similar also to \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in} which works

Comment: @cmhughes I tried it but it messed up my design (I started from a template I liked). This is why I am trying to do similar to the {topmargin} approach.

Comment: @karlkoeller I though you said that the solution would be simiar to {\addtolength{\textheight}{15pt}} not that this is your solution. I tried it, and it works. Thank you very much. I spent more than 2 hours on this. You should post an "answer post" to make this question have a clear answear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If for any reason you don't want to use the `geometry` package, something like

```
\addtolength{\textheight}{15pt}
```

should do what you want.

Increase (or decrease) the `15pt` value to meet your needs.